# Python plistlib: not nesting properly?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, plist

My code:

```
current_bex = dict(
    objectName = 'myData',
    objects = list(
        dict(
            one = 1,
            foo = 'bar',
        ),
    ), )

try:
        writePlist(current_bex, 'someFile.plist') except TypeError:
        print 'caught typeerror'
```

results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>objectName</key>
    <string>myData</string>
    <key>objects</key>
    <array>
        <string>foo</string>
        <string>one</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My question is, why, in the nested array, do I have simple strings, rather than <key>foo</key><string>bar</string>, etc?

EDIT:

```
current_bex = dict(
    objectName = 'myData',
    objects = [
        {
            'one': 1,
            'foo': 'bar',
        },
        {
            'something': 'goes here',
        },
    ],
)
```

works fine.  Apparently my use of dict() and list() is incorrect?  Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things here:

1. The `list()` constructor doesn't take individual content items as arguments, it takes an iterable of items. So you can write the list literal syntax`[1, 2, 3]`, but not `list(1, 2, 3)`.
2. A dict is iterable, and yields its keys as its values.

So, if you construct a list from a dict, the result will be a list of the keys of the dict, not a list containing a dict. That's exactly what you're seeing in the resulting plist.

```
>>> list(dict(one=1, foo='bar'))
['foo', 'one']
```